# Restarting a service in node-windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-services, daemon, node-windows

Using the [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) package, I am installing a node server locally as a service. Having then an interface to modify the .env file, when I actually modify the configurations of the .env and save the changes, the issue is that the service does not restart as it is supposed to, in order to acknowledge these changes. Can anyone guide me if there any other way to handle service restarts from this package, or any other workarounds similiar? I actually am trying to handle the restart like this:

```
const path = require("path");
let Service = require("node-windows").Service;
let EventLogger = require("node-windows").EventLogger;
const Messages= require("./models/messagesModel").getInstance();    
let filePathServer = path.resolve(__dirname, "app.backend.js");

class ServiceInstall {

    constructor(envConfig) {

    this.log = new EventLogger(envConfig.SERVICE_NAME);
    this.svc = new Service({
        name: envConfig.SERVICE_NAME,
        description: envConfig.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION,
        script: filePathServer,
        wait: envConfig.SERVICE_WAIT,
        grow: envConfig.SERVICE_GROW
    });
    }

    installWindowsService() {
        // event handlers to install the service
    }

    restartWindowsService(){
            this.svc.on("stop", () => {
                this.log.info("Service " + this.svc.name + " stopped!");
                Messages.info("Service " + this.svc.name + " stopped!");
            });
            this.svc.on("start", () => {
                this.log.info("Service " + this.svc.name + " started!");
                Messages.info("Service " + this.svc.name + " started!");
            });
            this.svc.restart();
        }

    }

module.exports = ServiceInstall;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the install process, `node-windows` essentially performs two steps:

1. Creates a `.exe` file by making a copy from `winsw.exe` and make corresponding entry in Windows Registry, so Windows can recognize this `.exe` as a Windows Service.
2. Use values passed into the Service constructor to generate a `.xml` file of the same name.

What this means is that once the `.xml` has been created, any changes that apply to inputs to the constructor function would not be carried into the `.xml` file, unless you do a complete re-install of the service [using `svc.uninstall()` followed by `svc.install()`]

If you want dynamically changing inputs, but without requiring a re-install, you should put those values in a `config.json` and then simply `require` that `config.json` *from within the script* you are trying to host as a Windows Service.

Now, if you make a change to `config.json` you just need to restart the service to reflect the change.

Also, if you don't want to manually do the restart everytime `config.json` changes, use `nodemon` in `execPath` instead of `node` in the config object passed to the `Service` constructor.